# Is it Possible to modify or update message of a topic by kafkacat?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb, kcat

I am trying to built an alert streaming application with confluent platform community & ksql headless mode. My application flow is I produce message (json format which have column like threshold, alert_flag, device_id etc.) to a base ksql stream with a topic. Another query of ksql filter that stream and generate alert to another table and publish alert stream to another topic. Now I want to change threshold and flag data for secific device_id of first topic on the fly by kafkacat or anyhow. is it possible?

Comment: Messages are immutable and kafkacat doesn't have any message editing features. But yes, it's possible to write new data to another topic... Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: No, I need to modify my first stream/ topic data like on or off alert for specific device_id by changing alert_flag 0/1

Comment: Okay, then, like I said, messages are immutable. You need a new topic

Comment: Can't we enrich a message ?